# Is there a Feature-Feedback in QWC 2 (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis-web-client

Is there a Feature-Feedback for QWC 2 (Qgis web client 2), where users can send some information for example wrong map information?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware QWC2 (QGIS-Webclient 2) is a bundle of tools you use to build your own map application. Of course they prepared a demo application for you to use, test and to explore what QWC2 has to offer. Any changes/improvements are up to the user to develop.

It would help to tell us what you would want to do/develop so we could point you in the right direction.

But if what you want to do/develop is not in the QWC2 you can find the mail list [here](https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-qwc2) and write a Feature-Feedback.

You could also file an issue on the QGIS Web Client 2 Demo Application pages on [GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/qwc2-demo-app/issues)